# unable to get value of checkbox using ngModel

Tags: angular, ionic4

I try to get the value of a checkbox, but I got undefined in my console. 
When I will be able to get the value, I will save the data into firebase.

```
              <ion-item *ngFor='let rep of reponse;let i = index'>
                  <ion-label>{{rep.name}}</ion-label>
                    <ion-checkbox 
                           [(ngModel)]="rep.checked"
                           color="primary" 
                           (ngModelChange)="updatedCheckList(i)"
                           slot="start"
                           >
                    </ion-checkbox>
                  </ion-item>
 <ion-button (click)="onClick()"></ion-button>
```

and my typescript code: 
For instance, I just try to console.log the value, inside my `onClick()` function.

```
private rep: any = {};
reponse = [
  {
    name: 'test',
    checked: false
  },
  {
    name: 'test2',
    checked: false
  },
  {
    name: 'test3',
    checked: false
  },
];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  updatedCheckList(itemIndex: number) {
    this.reponse.forEach((rep, index) => {
      if (itemIndex !== index) {
        rep.checked = false;
      }
    });
  }

  onClick() {
    console.log(this.rep.name);
  }
```

Don't know if it's the correct way but I found a solution. In updateCheckList I had : `this.index = itemIndex;`
Here is what I had in my .ts file.

```
index: number;
 onClick() {
console.log(this.reponse[this.index].name);
  }
```

Comment: "this.rep" will not work, as rep is the temp variable created inside ngFor you can't access from the TS. post your ts code also and explain what is your end goal will try to answer

Comment: I did update. Just try to get the value of the checkbox to store it inside firebase. @RavinSinghD Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to manage it yourself with the `updatedCheckList`, just setting the ngModel to `reponse[i].checked` will automatically toggle it when the checkbox is clicked:

```
            <ion-item *ngFor='let rep of reponse;let i = index'>
              <ion-label>{{rep.name}}</ion-label>
                <ion-checkbox 
                       [(ngModel)]="reponse[i].checked"
                       color="primary" 
                       slot="start"
                       >
                </ion-checkbox>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-button (click)="onClick()"></ion-button>
```

## Update - How to access values

Your values are always there, but the `i` in the template is only in the template.

In any event of your choice, such as a click event of a button, you can access the `reponse` array.

I've seen your other question now, are you still wanting to incorporate the unselecting others (as this is not a good idea, users expect the radio button to be mutually exclusive, and the checkbox to be as many "as as you like")

If you want to get one specific checkbox value then you just use the number of the index:

```
let checked = this.reponse[1].checked;
```

If you want to loop them you can put in its own for loop and do something with it:

```
onClick() {
   for(let index = 0; index < reponse.length; index++) {
     console.log(`Index ${index) has a checked value of ${reponse[index].checked}`);
   }
}
```

Which will show you all values.

Btw im using [template strings](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/template-strings.html) which is a great way to do string interpolation in typescript that is very readable.

Also btw, this is a good way to learn the basics but far from how Firebase actually works. You need to learn a whole bunch of concepts to understand how firebase saves it's data that you absolutely won't figure out from just trying to inch forward with the code yourself. You need to find a proper tutorial for that. It uses observable streams and updates in real time, it's not like a traditional way you might have done it with a mysql and php or anything like that.

Comment: thanks! how do I use this [I] in my .ts file. I tried to create I:number; and call it as I did before this.reponse[this.i].name but those not seems to work... (and thanks but yes I'am French :) ) @rtpHarry

Comment: OK :) I've removed my typo advice :P and updated the question. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for all those explanations ! @rptHarry

Comment: thanks for marking it as the answer, please could you consider upvoting it as well if it helped because, bizarrely, answers don't count towards my ionic4 tag badge, only upvotes.